# Whatsapp with twilio rejects all templates with Invalid format error

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I created about 10 templates and all of them were rejected with the reason Invalid format: The template content has an invalid format. Submit another template with the correct format.

What should I do, how to understand what the problem is, I even used the template that Twilio itself offers

I even used the template that Twilio itself offers

Here are a few options I have tried:

1. "Your One-Time Password code for {{1}} application is *{{2}}*."
2. "Your login code for {{1}} is {{2}}"
3. "Your One-Time Password code for Statfluence application is *{{2}}*."
4. "Your One-Time Password code for {{1}} application is {{2}}."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested it and these templates also gets rejected. Apparently Meta changed the requirements for the templates and you cannot end a template with a placeholder.

I tried a template that doesn't end with a placeholder and that worked:

> ```
> Your One-Time Password code for {{1}} application is {{2}}.
> Please enter it in the web application.
> ```

Comment: yes, it`s work for me. Thanks. Also i have checked meta documentation and found the same rule

Comment: Great!  If you found this answer helpful, please go ahead and use the "checkmark" button to accept it.